# How to start and stop 2 or more progressbar?

Tags: java, android

Hello stackoverflow citizen!
I want start and stop 2 progressBars on 1 activity.
I think oll progressBars must start in new thread and join with others.
For 1 progressBar i am write this code.

```
startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            handler.post(runnable);

        }
    });

    stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    });



}
int prolength=0;

Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

            prolength = inProgressBar.getProgress() + 1;
            inProgressBar.setProgress(prolength);
            timeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(prolength));

            if (prolength < 100) {
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
            }

            else {
                inProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                timeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(0));
               handler.post(runnable);
            }

        }

};
```

Thank you advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use sendMessage Api instead of post Api.
You can pass some information using Message object in your case (contentProgressBar1 or 2 or3 view) and refactor you implementation to this design..

Make sure to cleanup handler in activity life cycle else you will introduce memory leak and unwanted bugs.